# Spring boot security with OAuth2 for google login

Tags: spring-security, google-oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to configure a security layer in my project using spring boot with OAuth2.0 for google login and basic http form authentication. I could invoke the google login and i can access the protected resources from google but when i tried to authenticate from google i'm getting following error,                                    **There was an unexpected error (type=Unauthorized, status=401).
Authentication Failed: No AuthenticationProvider found for com.samsoft.oauth2.filter.CustomOAuth2AuthenticationToken**

I have shared the code in github repository. Please look on the below link to see the code i'm working on.

```
    [https://github.com/divat/spring-oauth-google-login/tree/master/spring-oauth2-login][1]
```

TIA.,